# Differences between directional derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In our Calc 3 class, we have started doing directional derivative and their applications.

So, for a function $f(x,y)$, the value of $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx}$ is used to determine what type of critical point occurs at any point where $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$. (Whether it is a local max, local min, or saddle point)

Often our teachers turns the term $f_{xy}f_{yx}$ into ${f_{xy}}^2$. They claim that for simple functions $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$, that the two directional derivatives are the same.

Is this always true? If it isn't, under what conditions is it false? Are there any especially good examples or counterexamples for this?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem

Comment: @user84413 thanks. If you elaborate a bit, and include the link as an answer, I will gladly accept the answer.

Comment: Since the MSE moderators frown on giving answers that consist of links, I will instead provide another link that gives a nice proof of Clairaut's theorem: http://www.math.duke.edu/~wka/math103/newmixed.pdf

Comment: Similar questions have been asked several times before here. Search for "mixed partial derivatives".